# How to use Dask to parallelize iterating and updating numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, dask

I have an extremely large distance matrix that I need to iterate through each value and update the distance if a condition is true.

Here is my Pandas/Numpy code chunk:

```
dist_mat = pd.read_csv()
date_list = metadata['sample_collection_date'].values
numpy_arr = dist_mat.values
columns = dist_mat.columns.tolist()
col_index = 0
for i in range(dist_mat.shape[0]):
    numpy_arr[i][i] += 0.1
    for j in range(col_index):
        if abs(np.timedelta64(date_list[i] - date_list[j], 'D')) <= 14:
                numpy_arr[i][j] += 0.1
                numpy_arr[j][i] += 0.1
    col_index += 1
```

I've tried to use Dask, but it is not any faster than what I have with Pandas/Numpy. I am wondering what is the correct way that will help process this code chunk in parallel.

```
dist_mat = dd.read_csv(args.dist_file, sep='\t', skiprows=2, sample=10000000, assume_missing=True).set_index('#Sources')

date_list = metadata['sample_collection_date'].values
np_array = dist_mat.to_dask_array(lengths=True)
columns = dist_mat.columns.tolist()
col_index = 0
for i in range(dist_mat.shape[0].compute()):
    numpy_arr[i][i] += 0.1
    for j in range(col_index):
        if abs(np.timedelta64(date_list[i] - date_list[j], 'D')) <= 14:
                numpy_arr[i][j] += 0.1
                numpy_arr[j][i] += 0.1
    col_index += 1
```

Comment: Please remove this `bar` stuff, as we have no idea what it is.

Comment: I've removed it. It was just a progress bar

Answer (score -1):

The problem seems to be that your current Dask code, you call the `.compute()` within a loop. Which can be very costly for the computational time and memory.

A more efficient approach might be to use `Numba` library, which can JIT compile python code and can make use of multiple cores for certain types of operations - specifically the `ufuncs`.

**Heres an example**:

```
import numba
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

@numba.njit(parallel=True)
def update_matrix(dist_mat, date_list, threshold=14, increment=0.1):
    N = dist_mat.shape[0]
    for i in numba.prange(N):
        dist_mat[i, i] += increment
        for j in range(i):
            if abs(np.timedelta64(date_list[i] - date_list[j], 'D')) <= threshold:
                dist_mat[i, j] += increment
                dist_mat[j, i] += increment
    return dist_mat

# Load your data
metadata = pd.read_csv('metadata.csv')
dist_mat = pd.read_csv('dist_mat.csv')

date_list = metadata['sample_collection_date'].values
dist_mat = dist_mat.values

# Update matrix
dist_mat = update_matrix(dist_mat, date_list)
```